# How to trap a PASTE in a TEXT widget

Tags: swt

I have a TEXT entry field. I want to limit the entry to letters or digits. Other characters should be converted to an under-score. The following code does this. However when the user pastes into the field, it bypasses the listener and the raw text is put into the field

```java
private class TextKeyVerifyListener implements VerifyListener
{
    @Override
    public void verifyText( VerifyEvent event )
    {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit( event.character ))
            event.text = "" + Character.toUpperCase( event.character ); 

        else if (!Character.isISOControl( event.keyCode ))
            event.text = "_"; 
    }
}
```

How do I trap the paste action so at least I can re-parse the text field. It seems kind of heavy duty to do this in the modify listener for each keystroke. Any solution should be cross-platform :-)

Trapping for CTRL-V might do this, but the user can also use the pop menu and choose paste.

Comment: Note: The `keyCode` field is **not** a Unicode value - you should not be testing it with `Character.isISOControl`

Comment: I'm using it to not swallow arrow, backspace, delete, etc key presses. Otherwise a backspace would be considered a non digit/letter key and produce an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

`VerifyEvent` has a `text` field containing all the text to be verified. You should be using this rather than the `character` field. `text` is set to the full pasted text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone else trying to do this:

```
     if (event.keyCode == 0 || !Character.isISOControl( event.keyCode ))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            char[] chars = event.text.toCharArray();

            for (char character : chars)
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit( character ))
                    text.append( Character.toUpperCase( character ) );
                else
                    text.append( "_" ); //$NON-NLS-1$

            event.text = text.toString();
        }
```

It's a little heavy for single keystrokes, but it will convert as I wanted.

Thanks!